# Getting old value of field in Firestore with Swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, xcode10, swift5

I'm trying to get the old value of a field when it is changed in Firestore. Is there any way to access what the previous value of a field is after it is changed? Here is my current code, I want to access the old `nickName` under `.modified` and print out what the new `nickName` is and also the old one.

```
db.collection("cities").whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
    guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
        print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
        return
    }
    snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
        if (diff.type == .added) {
            print("New city: \(diff.document.data())")
        let nickName = myData["nickName"] as? String ?? ""
        }
        if (diff.type == .modified) {
            let nickName = myData["nickName"] as? String ?? ""
        }
        if (diff.type == .removed) {
            let nickName = myData["nickName"] as? String ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not a feature of Firestore. What you can do is have another field `oldNickName` and using Firebase Functions, automatically update that when the `nickName` field is changed.

The best solution is storing `nickName` locally, so you can refer back to your local variable when `nickName` changes, accessing the newly updated one in the database and the previous `nickName` locally. Here is the updated code:

```
var nickNames = [String : String]()
db.collection("cities").whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
    guard error == nil, let snapshot = snapshot?.documentChanges else { return }
    snapshot.forEach {
        let document = $0.document
        let documentID = document.documentID
        let nickName = document.get("nickName") as? String ?? "Error"
        switch $0.type {
            case .added:
                print("New city: \(document.data())")
                nickNames[documentID] = nickName
            case .modified:
                print("Nickname changed from \(nickNames[documentID]) to \(nickName)")
                nickNames[documentID] = nickName
            case .removed:
                print("City removed with nickname \(nickNames[documentID])")
                nickNames.removeValue(forKey: documentID)
        }
    }
}
```

`nickNames` is a dictionary with key `cityID` and value `nickName`. This code is written in `Swift 5`.

Comment: You marked it as the correct answer, but didn't upvote it. Sorry if this is annoying

Comment: no i did both but i got this msg “feedback submitted thanks for the feedbak! cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score”